# Idempotent Powershell word search/replace across documents with headers, change tracking, etc

Tags: powershell, ms-office

I've found [one](http://www.powershell.nu/2009/02/05/replacing-text-in-word-documents-through-powershell/) or [two](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/05/14/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-look-for-and-replace-a-word-in-a-microsoft-word-document.aspx) guides to doing a word search and replace across multiple documents with powershell. They work well on simple documents. However, the script ignores text in headers and footers; and if "track changes" is enabled, it replaces text which has already been replaced, resulting in multiple copies of the new text if I run the script more than once on the same file.

Any clues as to how I can avoid these undesirable behaviors and make this script robust?

(reposted from [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/221147/idempotent-powershell-word-search-replace-across-documents-with-headers-change-t)).

Answer (score 1):

For replacing text in all parts of a Word document see:

[Using a macro to replace text where ever it appears in a document](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm)